# Actualizar numero cada hora con setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, wordpress

Por ahora solo he podido hacer este codigo

```
var time = 1;
var myInterval = setInterval(funtion(){
    time += 1;
},3600000)
});
```

Necesito que en un div, cada vez el numero se aumente despues de una hora,

```
<div id="time">1</div>
```

El problema tambien es que ese numero sea guardado en cookies, o en una pequeña sql, algo, para que sin importar que recarguen la pagina, siga desde el numero que quedo.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Juan David: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. En tu pregunta abarcas varias cosas pero sólo has indicado lo que has intentado en una de ellas. Lo ideal sería que buscaras/investigaras sobre todo lo que abarca la pregunta. En algunos casos conviene publicar cada parte por separado, conforme vayas avanzando en tu búsqueda/investigación. Por favor sigue el [tour] y consulta [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer una solución sin uso de Javascript ni cookies de la siguiente forma:

1. Crear una tabla con una columna llamada "fecha" del tipo `DATETIME`
2. Insertas la fecha y hora actual en dicha columna `INSERT INTO fechas (fecha) VALUES (now());`
3. Cada vez que se carga la pagina mostrás la diferencia `SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),fecha),'%H') FROM pruebafecha.fechas LIMIT 1;`

Haciendo uso de la variable $wpdb de wordpress sería:

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $horas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),fecha),'%H') FROM pruebafecha.fechas LIMIT 1");
?>
<div id="time"><?php echo $horas ?></div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo tengo una pregunta, cada vez que la pagina se actualice mostrara, la diferencia por hora cierto?

Comment: Exactamente! :D Ya no tenés que andar preocupandote por los coockies y los `setIntervals()`. Si querés mas precisión podés consultar por los minutos y segundos reemplazando `"%H"` por `"%H:%i:%s"`

Comment: @JuanDavid si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor márcala como  correcta para dar por cerrada la pregunta

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he publicado otra pregunta acerca de tu codigo, [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49302/agregar-shortcode-plugin-custom]

Comment: Buenísimo! Cuando llego a casa la veo y si puedo ayudo! Saludos!