# agregar Shortcode plugin custom

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

a todos!

Tengo este codigo,

```
<?php


add_action('wp_head', 'app_searched_today_visitbh');
function app_searched_today_visitbh(){
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $horas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),date_people),'%H') FROM today_people.date_people LIMIT 1"); 

}
add_shortcode('appsearchedtodayvisitbh', 'app_searched_today_visitbh'); 
?>
<div id="time"><?php echo $horas?></div>
```

Necesito de sus conocimientos y su ayuda.

Tengo un problema al activar el **plugin**, da error, en este caso el codigo funciona para mostrar un numero basado en la hora que se encuentra en la table de la db, necesito hacer que el resultado se muestre en un `Shortcode`, pero no encuentro el error.

Muchas Gracias

---

IMPORTANTE ACTUALIZACION.

```
function app_searched_today_visitbh() {
    global $wpdb;
    $horas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),date_people),'%H') FROM today_people.date_people LIMIT 1"); 
    return ("<div id='time'>$horas</div>");
}

add_shortcode('appsearchedtodayvisitbh', 'app_searched_today_visitbh');
```

El codigo ha quedado de esta manera, solo tengo un error mas.

Al crear la *today_people* y añadirle una columna *date_people* y ejecutar la siguiente consulta `INSERT INTO today_people (date_people) VALUES (now());`
luego activar el plugin, en el front no muestra el resultado.

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

Comment: @genarito me ayudarias! , Muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias @angel-angel, soy nuevo en esta plataforma. me disculpan si mi pregunta no estuvo bien detallada.

Comment: No problem bienvenido, de todas forma no estaba mal comparada con muchas otras, solo que si la leo y creo que con algun cambio puede ayudar a otros a leer y entender mejor, suelo hacerlo .Solo quise recalcar algunos detallas, ademas tu pregunta estaba bien por lo menos tenia formato de codigo.

Comment: Gracias! si eso es bueno ayudar a corregir! como dicen ( sin reglas o formatos somos bestias ) . ;) Muchas gracias @AngelAngel

Comment: Hola, @JuanDavid, si la tabla se llama today_people y la columna es date_people la consulta debería ser `"SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),date_people),'%H') FROM today_people LIMIT 1"`

Comment: @Genarito Funciona! mil gracias, una pregunta mas, en este momento muestra `<span id='days_since'>00</span>` , porque? el resultado es 00

Comment: Sinceramente no tengo idea, podrías probar abriendo otra pregunta con ese tema en específico (estaría bueno que en ella incluyas capturas de pantalla y detalles de la base de datos) a ver que responde el resto de los usuarios. PD: ten en cuenta que la consulta a la base de datos está basada en código MySQL

Comment: @Genarito ya funciono solo cambie a %i :) gracias

Comment: De nada! Encantado de poder ayudar, ten en cuenta que `%i` solo daría los minutos! Fijate en http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp todos los formatos disponibles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los shortcode deben retornar un HTML para poder ser usados, en este caso tu código quedaría así dentro del archivo `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'app_searched_today_visitbh');
function app_searched_today_visitbh() {
    global $wpdb;
    $horas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),date_people),'%H') FROM today_people.date_people LIMIT 1"); 
    return ("<div id='time'>" . $horas . "</div>");
}
add_shortcode('appsearchedtodayvisitbh', 'app_searched_today_visitbh');
```

Luego creás una nueva página y en el contenido ponés:

```
[appsearchedtodayvisitbh]
```

**Nota:** Hay otras formas de insertar código PHP en tus páginas, [acá](https://geekytheory.com/wordpress-ejecutar-codigo-php-en-paginas-sin-plugin/) te explican cómo, por si te interesa o te sirve en el futuro.

Espero haberte ayudado! Saludos!

Comment: Muchas GRacias! @Gernarito , leere tu post, apenas tenga los suficientes puntos, te doy 1 punto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Para tu info... estás mezclando `PHP` con `JS`... en `PHP` se concatena con `.`

Comment: Uhhh me confundí! Mil gracias! Ahí edito

Comment: Una ayuda con la actualizacion @Genarito :)

Comment: Ahí te respondí como comentario en la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Esto es una respuesta orientativa.

Estás confundiendo las diferentes API de Wordpress y sus funcionamiento.

Una es el uso de la [`API shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), los `shortcodes` son pequeñas funciones donde lo activas en el panel de control en los editores de `posts` o `pages`.

Si escogemos tu código sería (mas o menos):

```
function app_searched_today_visitbh() {

    global $wpdb;
    $horas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),date_people),'%H') FROM today_people.date_people LIMIT 1"); 
    // retornamos
    return "<div id='time'>$horas</div>";
}

add_shortcode('appsearchedtodayvisitbh', 'app_searched_today_visitbh');
```

Y para usar el `shortcode` tienes que usar la sintaxis parecidas como `HTML`, pero en vez de `<>` usamos corchetes `[]`, ej.: `[appsearchedtodayvisitbh]`.

---

El uso de la [`API Hooks`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) es mucho más complejo, pero en principio llama (acciona) la función según donde lo *enganches*.

Es decir si usamos por ejemplo `wp_head` se activa dentro de la sección `<head></head>` del tema.

Un ejemplo:

```
<?php 
function hook_javascript() { ?>

    <script>
       alert('Página esta cargando...');
    </script>

<?php 
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_javascript');
?>
```

Ahora si quieres crear un plugin te recomiendo que leas el [`Codex de Wordpress - Plugin`](https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Escribiendo_un_Plugin) y buscar tutoriales.

[Codex - Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu buena respuestas y la explicación de cada cosa, voy a leer sobre crear plugins! es bueno aprender algo nuevo. lo mejor siempre es aprender

Comment: Solo un problema, el <div id='time'>$horas</div> no da el resultado.

Comment: @JuanDavid - Te debería funcionar, ahora si no funcione la consulta es otro tema...